# Error if I try to install node-java and node-jdbc witn npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to access a H2 database through a Nodejs server including `jdbc library (node-jdbc)`.
I work on Windows 7 and I have the JDK1.8 installed. Node-jdbc needs node-java. When I run `"npm i java"` (same error if I run `"npm i jdbc"`)

> gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
>   gyp ERR! configure error 
>   gyp ERR! stack Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.20.23.46:443 
>   gyp ERR! stack     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1174:14) gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601 
>   gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\g073242\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" 
>   gyp ERR! cwd C:\Nodejs Test Server\node_modules\java 
>   gyp ERR! node -v v9.11.2 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2 
>   gyp ERR! not ok
>   npm WARN restfulserver@1.0.0 No description 
>   npm WARN restfulserver@1.0.0 No repository field. 
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE 
>   npm ERR! errno 1 
>   npm ERR! java@0.11.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild` 
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1 
>   npm ERR! 
>   npm ERR! Failed at the java@0.11.0 install script. 
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

And the detailed log is as follows:

```
913 verbose stack Error: java@0.11.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
913 verbose stack Exit status 1
913 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\g073242\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:304:16)
913 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:180:13)
913 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\g073242\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
913 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:180:13)
913 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:936:16)
913 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5)
914 verbose pkgid java@0.11.0
915 verbose cwd C:\Nodejs Test Server
916 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
917 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\g073242\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i" "java"
918 verbose node v9.11.2
919 verbose npm  v6.1.0
920 error code ELIFECYCLE
921 error errno 1
922 error java@0.11.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
922 error Exit status 1
923 error Failed at the java@0.11.0 install script.
923 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
924 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: NodeJS is for JavaScript code. JavaScript is a completely different language and ecosystem than Java. All they share is the first 4 letters in their name.

Comment: Well I know that, but there are some libraries that allow you to use jdbc through NodeJS: node-jdbc for example. It also needs node-java.

Comment: Look at the actual error log before you post:  gyp ERR! stack Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.20.23.46:443   You have a connection issue, investigate that first.

Comment: node-gyp is involved, that always makes errors look like your machine is melting down. But at the surface it looks like a simple "Cannot connect to the database" error based on that connection timeout.

Comment: I added a more detailed log

Comment: are you running this command behind a proxy?

Comment: Yes. I have no problem to use npm install for other modules.

Comment: I tried without the proxy and I get this error which looks like the previous: gyp ERR! stack Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ETIMEDOUT 10.32.1.26:8080
gyp ERR! stack     at ClientRequest.onError (C:\Users\g073242\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:177:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:272:13)